# How to open tefillin

Tags: kashrut-kosher, tefilin, how-to

I do not have a sofer stam near me. How do you open up your tefillin's battim and insure the parshiyot inside are kosher? I suspect they are not kosher (at all), because they are a really cheap pair. I am working to replace them. I have even stopped reciting a bracha on them because I don't think they are valid.

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you're up for IMHO no offense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the boxes are kosher, you should get a real sofer to check them. If there isn't one near you, you can call a sofer in New York and ask if you can mail them in. (Since you live in Midland) There is a sofer in Dallas. Contact Congregation Toras Chaim for his information.

To open the tefillin:
You can open them up by cutting the sinews with a razor blade or exact-o knife. Pluck out the bits of sinew and you can open the top and bottom easily.

But to close them again you will need sinew. It needs to be from a kosher animal made by Jews and there is a special way of tying it.

The sealing of the top to the bottom I done with glue. It looks nicer and keeps out more moisture but is optional. It can be done carefully with a fine razor.

Comment: If the battim are sealed closed it won't be this easy.

Comment: If you do not know how to open them, you probably do not know how to check them properly in any case. You need to find a sofer.